# How to handle YADView events to create new elements

Tags: android, android-calendar

I intend to create an application that can show a weekview and a dayview. I searched a lot and mostly found calendars that can show a month view. Nothing else.

I found some dayview calendar but they were very amateur in design.

The only promising project was [YADView](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/source/browse/) which remarkably resembles the built-in calendar. So I was optimistic that I can use it and don't have to create my own implementation.

I tested its apk and I saw that it is mostly about design (very pretty), you only can see some events in the calendar (added in a mock resource). It is *not* connected to the Google Calendar.

Based on its operation, I assumed it is about 2-400 lines of code (excluding the design code).

Then I opened its source code. I was horrified. It consist of **8000** loc (yes, *8 thousand* loc). To show a colorful oblong in a gray background and be able to swipe. And its structure... There is a loader that uses a view, created by a factory that holds event loaders that are based on interfaces which are implemented in various classes to be added as parameters to more vague methods... if someone thinks that this is maintainable...

So, I try to add events to this...creature when the user presses a cell.

I see that an eventbus is used, but when firing the new event creation, nothing is shown.

Where can I find the new event dialog in it?

Answer (score 1):

I started working through the YADView project today for an app that I am busy with. I see your question was posted a while back, but perhaps I can help someone who stumbles upon your question a while later (like I did).

I could be wrong, but I think you are looking for something that does not form part of the project. The UI for the event creation process is left up to you to implement (whether it is with a dialog or a new activity - do it how you wish).

Take a look at the ["yadview-harness"](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/source/browse/yadview-harness/) part of the repository. This is a good example to get started with. Get it running and take a look at the files, I found that this was the best way to get going. Here is a summary.

Event creation is handled and shown in more detail in the [MockEventResource.java](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/source/browse/yadview-harness/src/com/google/gode/yadview_harness/MockEventResource.java) file.  You will see it is pretty straight forward.

The [YadViewHarnessDayViewFactory](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/source/browse/yadview-harness/src/com/google/gode/yadview_harness/YadviewHarnessDayViewFactory.java) file is where you can see how to handle the different action events (such as a when an event is created or selected). The app's default behavior is for a Toast message to pop up when you select an event:

```
public void handleShowDateEvent(ViewEventEvent e){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "test! " + e.getEvent().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}
```

You can take this further. If for example you want to handle when a new event needs to be created, you could implement it as follows:

```
@Subscribe
public void handleShowDateEvent(CreateEventEvent e){

}
```

In here you could trigger a Dialog to pop up so that you can input all the details for your new event.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but luckily I didn't have to work with this...I'm getting more and more disappointed over Android development. This new Gradle abomination that NEVER works...no, thanks. I'm very satisfied of how Microsoft handles development. _Everyone_ should follow their lead and not sink in this...